# Invoke Ant build file Jenkins 2 groovy pipeline

Tags: ant, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to update our build process using groovy pipelines in Jenkins. However, I am unable to figure out how to invoke Ant with a list of properties.

```
node {

 echo "Starting client build..."
 client()
}



def client() {
 stage('Build client') {
  echo "build from ${BRANCH} branch and delivered to ${DELIVERY_LOCATION} with update verison ${UPDATE_VERSION}"

  git branch: '${BRANCH}', credentialsId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', url: 'https://XXXX@bitbucket.org/REPO/test.git'

properties([[$class: 'JiraProjectProperty'], [$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: false], parameters([booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: '', name: 'HTTP'), string(defaultValue: '1.0', description: '', name: 'VERSION', trim: false), choice(choices: ['Packages', 'Updates', 'Release'], description: '', name: 'DELIVERY_LOCATION'), string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'UPDATE_VERSION', trim: false), choice(choices: ['master', 'development'], description: '', name: 'BRANCH'), string(defaultValue: '\\\\shares\\WebHelp', description: '', name: 'WEBHELP_SOURCE_FOLDER', trim: false)])])


  echo "properties: $params"
  withAnt(installation: 'apache-ant-1.9.14', jdk: 'JDK1.8.0_144') {

    Buildfile:'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\Test\\webclient\\build.xml'

   sh "ant package $params" 
 }
}
}
```

I cannot seem to specify the build file as I have in the past using `BuildFile: .....`

Once I can specify the build file I would like to pass in properties but I haven't gotten there yet.. Something like:

```
Properties: rel.dest=$DELIVERY_LOCATION
            major.version = $VERSION
            webhelp.src.folder = $WEBHELP_SOURCE_FOLDER
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most elegant solution, but I find it easiest to just reproduce what I would type in the terminal command:

```
sh 'ant package\
    -f /path/to/build.xml\
    -Dparam1=value1\
    -Dparam2=value2'
```

Comment: I tried passing it into the pipeline and it can't seem to find the path to the build file..

Comment: If there are spaces in your path, you'll probably need to put quotes around it, which can be a bit tricky since the entire command itself is in quotes. I'm not on Windows so I can't test this kind of path myself, though.